# Layer multiple images with transparency with TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using the TCPDF library to generate and export a pdf document from a server. I would like to layer several PNG images on the same page, in the same place (they would all be covering the entire page). When I try the code below, the pdf gets created after a very long time (more than one minute):

```
$pdf->AddPage();

// Add image
$pdf->Image("images/PNG-test/city_300DPI.png", 0, 0, $W, $H, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);

// Add image
$pdf->Image("images/PNG-test/lush_300DPI.png", 0, 0, $W, $H, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
```

It takes about the same time (i.e. unacceptably long) to put the same images on three different pages.

Converting the PNG images to JPEG makes the whole process incomparably faster, even thought the images have a larger individual file size (the PNGs weigh rougly 200KB each, while the JPEGs are about 400KB).

Could it be that TCPDF just can't handle PNGs properly ?

Comment: Please elaborate. What result are you getting and what was the desired outcome? Can you provide screenshots of both?

Comment: I could provide screenshots if necessary, but all I really want is to overlay any two png images on top of one another. The result I'm getting is no result at all, my php script running for a very long time without throwing any errors nor the intended pdf file.

Comment: If it's running for a long time and then quits without any output, it sounds like either an out-of-memory issue, or its execution time limit was exceeded. Either way, your stack should have logged this somewhere. Please look through your webserver or PHP's logs for any clues. From the looks of your filenames, 300 DPI PNGs may be big files, but I'm just speculating now.

Comment: @RoAchterberg I've done some more testing, and I've edited my question accordingly. Any idea what could cause the problem ?

Comment: How much faster are the JPEGs? How fast is it if you drop the alpha channel from the PNGs to test? Are you on the latest version of TCPDF? Have you tried profiling your script to see where it's taking such a long time?